# inline var bug with anonymous procedure?

Tags: delphi

with the code below:

```
Procedure TMyForm.doAction;
begin

    generateToken;
    VAR LToken := generatedToken; // Ltoken is set correctly to xxxxx

    //-----
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin

        GetData(LToken); // << here LToken is empty !!

      end).Start;

end;
```

As you can see, the value of LToken is empty inside the anonymous procedure (so the capture didn't work). if I don't use inline var for LToken then it's work

```
Procedure TMyForm.doAction;
Var LToken: ansiString;
begin
   ....
end;
```

Is this a bug or a know limitation ?

Comment: Yes, there was compiler bug https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-26666 fixed in 10.4

Comment: I can't see from that whether it has been fixed or rejected as "Expected behaviour". If the latter, I can certify that it is _not_ expected behaviour that the compiler allows it but produces unexpected results. It should either flag it as an error during compilation or work as expected (by a user - not by a compiler developer).

Comment: @HeartWare It is fixed as in works properly now and captures inline variable. I know because I have verified the fix with 10.4. Also, bugs rejected as expected behavior are not marked as Fixed but as "Won't Fix" or "Works as Expected". Fixed means really fixed.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Thanks. I was confused by the comment "_Expected behavior_ seen with Denali GetIt Integration Build ( 27.0.36919.8487 )."

Comment: @HeartWare That comment is merely stating since which build bug is corrected. It is feedback for developers and testers during development stage - pre release. When you have bug, you have wrong behavior, something is not working as expected. When the bug is fixed, you get correct, expected behavior. I posted an answer to make it more clear for future visitors bumping into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a compiler bug in Delphi 10.3.x and inline variables are not properly captured by anonymous methods.

Inline variables don't work with anonymous methods
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-26666

Solution for 10.3.x, as you already mentioned, is to define and use local variable instead of using inline variable.

Another solution would be upgrading to 10.4, where capturing inline variables with anonymous methods has been corrected and now it correctly captures inline variable, so you would be able to use your original code.

However, there is additional bug in compiler in 10.4 related to capturing inline variables. If the variable is managed type (interface reference, string...), it is never automatically released and it leaks memory.

Such variables must be explicitly released at the end of anonymous method that captured them. For instance, assigning nil to interface reference or assigning empty string to string variable...

Memory leak: inline Interfaces captured by anonymous methods are not released
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29564